# Check that the next char is end of array - java

Tags: java, buffer

So trying to create a method which goes through a string and checks each char for vowels.

However when it reaches the end and does a forward check for the char. i get a strings out of bound exception. i tried adding a check for whitespace for the char ahead but still get the exception.

```
   for (char i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                if (isVowel(key.charAt(i + 1)) && !Character.isWhitespace(key.charAt(i + 1))   {
                 buffer[i] = key.charAt(i);
                } else {
                  break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you not using strings? With arrays you always need to remember their lengths and use this to "know" when you are at the end of the array.

Comment: Why are you checking `i + 1` and not just `i`?

Comment: You should run loop till `i < key.length-1 ` but this will not check for the first character as loop starts checking from `i+1` and why did you declare `i` as `char`?

Comment: sorry typo...also im checking if the one ahead is a vowel, if it is then add it..also i cant use i < key.length-1, that misses the final char to check

Comment: What is the size of your buffer?

Comment: what about the first character? Looks like your `buffer` and `key` could have different length?

Comment: first character isnt necessary, as im checking ahead, if it is a vowel, i add the first character to the buffer. Also the buffer size is the string.toCharArray

Comment: Are you creating a `buffer` of the correct size ? You iterate `key` character to put them in `buffer`, if buffer is longer, it will not work because the loop use the `buffer` size.

Comment: buffer matches the length of the string. my problem is once it reaches the last character, my check for  + 1 throws an exception due it being the end of the array

Comment: @Matchbox2093 see my answer. The first part was answered by your comment but the rest is still valid. You need to stop the iteration before the last one. Now, if you still want to add that character, there is no condition (as there is no character), so you could check if you "break" the loop or not to add the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the buffer for a correct size like

```
char[] keyChar = key.toCharArray();
char[] buffer = new char[keyChar.length]; //same size
```

Then, iterate the key, not the buffer

```
for(int i = 0; i < keyChar.length -1; ++i)
```

And don't go to the end since you use [i + 1] in the logic.

Note that this will ignore the last character, you have to see if you want that last character or not in the buffer. If so, you will need to add it (without your check on the next one obviously)

Comment: thanks! i just separated out the logic for the last character and how to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

```
  for (char i = 0; i < buffer.length-1; i++) {
            if (isVowel(key.charAt(i + 1)) && !key.charAt(i + 1) && !Character.isWhitespace(key.charAt(i + 1))   {
             buffer[i] = key.charAt(i);
            } else {
              break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Won't compile for the same reason as pointed out in the comments.